# magento disable custom tab based on radio button option in customer registeration

Tags: jquery, magento

I am new to magento.I have created some custom form fields using varien_data_form and used in customer registration.

Totally three tabs are there in my customer registration:

```
    1. customer_vendor_tabs_registration_set_content
    2. customer_vendor_tabs_profile_set_content
    3. customer_vendor_tabs_profileother_set_content
```

My first tab contains some fields with a radio button called city, if I choose first option in my radio button then i just want to remove my 3'nd tab, similarly if i choose 2 option in my radio button then  i just want to remove my 2'nd tab.

I dont know how to do this?

Can anyone help????

Comment: are you talking about admin panel's side form ?

Comment: No, I am asking in frontend for customer registration.

Comment: did you try to write some jquery code ? I think you can do it with jquery as you need to hide a tab based on radio button' selection value.

Comment: I can do in jquery, i can only hide tab, but i wont be able to hide mandatory fields validation in that particular tab , right?